# jquery validation with multiple emails and regex

Tags: jquery, regex, validation, email

I didn't found a solution on the web and javascript is not my strength. Any attempt to integrate the verification also failed.

I'm using the following code to check my form:

```
$('#form').validate({
    errorContainer: ".form_errors",
    showErrors: function (errorMap, errorList) {
        $(".form_errors").html("<span>all red marked borders are required.</span>");
        this.defaultShowErrors();
    },
    invalidHandler: function(form, validator) {
    },
    errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
    },
    highlight: function(element) {
        $(element).closest('.check').addClass('error_border');
    },
    unhighlight: function(element) {
        $(element).closest('.check').removeClass('error_border');
    },
});
```

but i would verify multiple emails in one input field:

```
<input type="email" id="email" name="email" placeholder="eMails" autocomplete="off" class="check" required multiple>
```

with regex like this:

```
^(([a-zA-Z0-9_\-\.\+]+)@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.)|(([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+\.)+))([a-zA-Z]{2,4}|[0-9]{1,3})(\]?)(,\s?|\s?)){1,5}$
```

How is it possible with the jquery validation code above?

Thanks for help!

Comment: jquery valiation has the built in `email` validator,why do you want to do it yourself?

Comment: with regex i want to limit the maximum of emails to 5. is there a simpler solution?

Comment: Your emails must be separated by a semicolon or so. Split and then validate as usual.

Comment: how do i made the split and the validation with the code above? i can't do it - thx for help.